# Passwordless ssh for non-root user in Docker

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, docker

I'm running into a curious issue I've never seen before when setting up password-less SSH between docker nodes for a non-root user. To set the stage, here's what has worked:
For root user on node 1:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa ...
ssh-copy-id node2
```

I can now ssh from node1 -> node2 without password.

I use a different user (i.e. mark). I perform the same steps above, generating the keys & copying to node2 and still get the prompt. I turned on diagnostics (ssh -v node2) and got the following:

```
[mark@node1 ~]$ ssh -v node2
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to node2 [172.17.0.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
... more stuff
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
...
```

I find it odd, except in another post here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container) one of the posters made the following comment:
"Remember that docker runs with sudo (unless you don't), if this is the case you'll be using the root ssh keys." This caught my attention as I suspect that may be the essence of my problem.

Since I couldn't post a follow-up question there, I thought I'd reframe the question here. I can't find any details in the Docker documentation specifically on this but it does seem to influence the behavior of password-less ssh for non-root users.

I appreciate any clarity anyone can provide.

Comment: I should add that I can successfully do this from the host VM to node1. It seems to be some odd behavior of what the 'perceived' user is when issuing the ssh command. Even if I did 'ssh mark@node2), it still would result in the same attempt to use root's private key.

Comment: you could experiment with different values in authorized_keys in the destination system(ssh-copy-id appends public keys from the source system, to authorized_keys on the destination system). And experiment with specifying the private key with `ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa`

Comment: But it begs the question: If I'm logged in as user 'mark', why does it try to read /root/.ssh/id_rsa? It should be reading /home/mark/.ssh/id_rsa. Additionally, I've started with an empty authorized_keys file so as to be sure that only the one entry is there.

Comment: I don't know though I often try ssh from windows cygwin with just one user.. But how about when you experiment with ssh -i  specifying mark's key? I agree it wouldn't answer your question, though it's worth trying anyway.

Comment: Worth trying `ssh -i /home/mark/.ssh/id_rsa...` (or whatever path it is) to see if it even allows you to use mark's key and whether it works when doing that. Also, (forgetting -i) see if there is a file `~/.ssh/config`  if so if it has anything in it. And see if there is a line `IdentityFile ____`   in /etc/ssh_config that might be specifying root's key. And *as a test* try renaming root's key see what it does then!

Comment: Thank You!!! Those were both good suggestions. Yes, I could log in (password-less) using the -i option. And, yes, there was an entry for IndentityFile in /etc/ssh/ssh_config. I comment out out and Bob's your uncle, it worked.

Comment: glad it worked. I have posted it as an answer, you can accept it by clicking the tick next to it

Comment: Late and maybe silly question - why don't I see any mark@node2 or -u mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For troubleshooting / understanding what is going on, it's worth trying `ssh -i /home/mark/.ssh/id_rsa...` (or whatever path it is) to see if it even allows you to use mark's key and whether it works when doing that.  And as a test try renaming root's key see what it does then!

Also, (forgetting -i) see if there is a file ~/.ssh/config if so if it has anything in it. And see if there is a line `IdentityFile ____` in /etc/ssh_config that might be specifying root's key.